# How to pass a variable between function without loose any data

Tags: c, printf

I have a big problem, i have build a code where I catch rtc data and pass it to a string , with this I made the name of the file, based in year/month/day/hour/minuts/seconds. This way I assure there is no way to have two files with same name.
Based in this spintf convertion I send it to another page where I try to creat the file , but something goes wrong because this string does not arrive full.
example:

file1.c

```
char dateAndTimeFile[];
void setUserDefinedTime(int rtc_year, int rtc_month, int rtc_day, int rtc_hour, int rtc_minute, int rtc_second){
    /*CONVERT INTO SINGLE EXPRESSION FOR TIME FILE*/
     sprintf(dateAndTimeFile,"HealthFile20%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d%02dLOG.txt",
     rtc_year, rtc_month, rtc_day, rtc_hour, rtc_minute, rtc_second);
     setParameterCreateInputFile(dateAndTimeFile);
}
```

file2.c

```
char *inputfile;
void setParameterCreateInputFile(char str[]){
    inputfile = str;
    printf("file:%s\n", (TCHAR*)inputfile);

// all FULL string present
SDCARD_Open();
}

void SDCARD_Open(void){
printf("LOAD %s\n", (TCHAR*)inputfile);
//this code appear to be broken only show LOAD Heal
}
```

Comment: *but something goes wrong because this string does not arrive full* - what does that mean? Post a [mcve] and your output.

Comment: Anyway, if the code is like this, then `dateAndTimeFile` has no size defined and can't contain any string.

Comment: Per Eugene, the TL;DR: `char dateAndTimeFile[];` --> `char dateAndTimeFile[100];`

Comment: Remember, C does *not* have a first-class string type.  *You* must think about how big your strings are or might be, and you must explicitly allocate memory for them. When you said `char dateAndTimeFile[];`, you did *not* say "give me a string that's big enough, or that grows automatically, for whatever goes into it."  What you said in fact was, "Give me a uselessly small string that's not big enough to store anything."

Comment: And because strings might not  be big enough and do not grow, calling `sprintf` is often dangerous.  It's much safer to use `snprintf` instead, because it takes the array size as an explicit, separate parameter, meaning that you have to think about it, and `snprintf` knows it, so it can arrange not to overflow it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must make the array `dateAndTimeFile` large enough to store the string written by `sprintf`.

In the line

```
char dateAndTimeFile[];
```

you are not specifying the size of the array, so it is not guaranteed that the size is sufficient.

The string that `sprintf` writes will have a length of at least `31` characters (`32` including the null terminating character). Depending on the value of the integer arguments, the length may be larger.

Therefore, you must make the size of the array at least 32 bytes, like this:

```
char dateAndTimeFile[32];
```

However, unless you are on a platform with very little memory, it would probably be better to be generous, for example to set the size of the array to `100` or `200` bytes. Otherwise, you will risk a [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow).

For additional safety, I suggest that you use the function [`snprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) instead of `sprintf`. That way, a buffer overflow cannot occur, even in cases in which the string ends up being significantly longer than intended.

Instead of

```
sprintf(dateAndTimeFile,"HealthFile20%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d%02dLOG.txt",
     rtc_year, rtc_month, rtc_day, rtc_hour, rtc_minute, rtc_second);
```

I suggest that you write:

```
int wants_to_write = snprintf(
    dateAndTimeFile, sizeof dateAndTimeFile,
    "HealthFile20%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d%02dLOG.txt",
    rtc_year, rtc_month, rtc_day,
    rtc_hour, rtc_minute, rtc_second
);
if ( wants_to_write < 0 || wants_to_write >= sizeof dateAndTimeFile )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "Error writing to buffer!\n" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
```

That way, your program will print an error message if the buffer is not large enough, instead of overflowing the buffer (which may cause the program to crash).

Comment: Shouldn't they get a syntax error if there's no size in the array declaration? It can only be empty if it's a function parameter or there's an initializer.

Comment: @Barmar: Both gcc and clang only emit a warning, even when compiling with `-std=c18 -pedantic-errors`, and they set the array size to `1`. [As far as the ISO C standard is concerned, an array without a size is an "incomplete type"](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p22). However, I am unsure what consequences this has. As far as I can tell, using such an array is not a contraint violation (syntax error).

Comment: friends, thanks for your answer, it really was a mistake on my part, I actually wrote the variable dateAndTime, and I left the insertion of the dimension of the array for later, after building the sprintf function. However I was curious, what are the benefits I can get by replacing the sprintf function with snprintf

Comment: @ArmandoFerreira: The function `snprintf` will limit the number of bytes written to the buffer, so that a [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) cannot occur. With the function `sprintf`, on the other hand, there is a danger of a buffer overflow. A buffer overflow is very bad, because it can cause your program to crash, or, even worse, overwrite important data in your program that causes your program to misbehave in a way that is very hard to debug.

Comment: @ Andreas Wenzel, thanks for your support and explanations, I will take in good count this, and apply it in the right time.
Thanks in advance for everything